# Wildcard SSL certificate with automatic subdomain forwarding

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, tls

I have a server where, as part of the service, users are given their own personalised subdomain, i.e. username.servicename.com. It's not particularly feasible to generate personalised vhost entries every time this happens, so I used a wildcard virtualhost file in Apache. This works great.

I'm now trying to get SSL working on it. I have a wildcard SSL certificate with a CommonName of *.servicename.com, so I think I'm doing what I should be doing. But... doesn't work. HTTP requests still work fine, HTTPS requests time out, and there's nothing in the logs. What is wrong with my config?

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    DirectoryIndex index.htm index.html index.php

    <VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName servicename.com
        ServerAlias *.servicename.com #wildcard catch all
        VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1
        UseCanonicalName Off
        IndexOptions FancyIndexing
        ### Use mod_rewrite to direct servicename.com to www.
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^servicename.com
        RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
        ### Logging
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log_servicename combined

        <Directory /var/www>
            Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName servicename.com
        ServerAlias *.servicename.com
        VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1
        UseCanonicalName Off
        IndexOptions FancyIndexing
        ### Use mod_rewrite to direct servicename.com to www.
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^servicename.com
        RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
        ### Logging
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log_servicename combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol all
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/servicename.com.certificate
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/servicename.com.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/rapidssl.intermediateca

        <Directory /var/www>
            Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-ssl.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You've verified that the firewall allows port 443 traffic, that "netstat -anp |grep 443" shows apache listening on that port, "apache2ctl configtest" shows now errors, and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty strange to see requests to Apache to time out because of a wrong configuration.

When a connection times out, it often is a problem of networking or firewall. For example, if firewall is configure not to allow traffic on that port and it drops those packets, the connection will time out.

Have a look at all the firewall involved in your setup, and this means your local network outgoing rules, the server network incoming rules and the iptables rules of the server itself.

Comment: Totally correct - Amazon EC2 firewall was blocking :443.